# How to capture external keyboard keypress

Tags: android

How to capture key-press from external usb keyboard attached to android device?
I need it to enable games that requires touchscreen on devices that does not have one (like Android TV Box). For example capture arrow keys press and generate swipe down event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreground activity can "capture arrow keys press" from an external keyboard the same way as it would for anything else, by overriding methods like `onKeyDown()`.

If you are thinking that you will spy on input to arbitrary apps, that is not supported by the Android SDK. There's probably some solution for rooted devices that works at the lower Linux levels.